# How to Store the returned variable from one class to another class variable?

Tags: c#

Form1.cs

```
public String Return_inf()
{
    names = U_name.Text;
    return names;   
}
```

And i try to store it in another class string variable like :

```
public string  CheckLogin()
{
     Form1 f = new Form1();
     string name=f.Return_inf();
 }
```

But the variable is empty ....

Comment: Where are you getting the value in `U_name.Text`?

Comment: It is the value that is fetched from the textBox

Comment: Just for the sake of finding the cause... Try setting names in your `Return_inf()` method to something constant. See if that works, if it does then we know the problem is reading that textbox.

Comment: wait.. you create a new form and then instantly read U_name.Text from it. I dont think you eneter anythign into that form or even show it

Answer (score 1):

The reason your variable name is empty is because you are creating a brand new Form1 object in your CheckLogin() method, instead of using an already existing Form1 object.

You could have your classes have references to one another.

Here is one example you could try by having the forms have references to one another

Form1 class:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    // Class variable to have a reference to Form2
    private Form2 form2;

    // Constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        // InitializeComponent is a default method created for you to intialize all the controls on your form.
        InitializeComponent();

        form2 = new Form2(this);
    }

    public String Return_inf()
    {
        names = U_name.Text;
        return names;
    }
}
```

Form2 class:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    // Class variable to have a reference back to Form1
    private Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    public string CheckLogin()
    {
        // There is no need to create a Form1 object here in the method, because this class already knows about Form1 from the constructor
        string name=form1.Return_inf();

        // Use name how you would like
    }  
}
```

There are other ways of doing this, but IMO this would be the basics of sharing data between two forms.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by defining static class like this

```
static class GlobalClass
{
    private static string U_name= "";

    public static string U_name
    {
        get { return U_name; }
        set { U_name= value; }
    }
}
```

and you can use it as follow

```
GlobalClass.U_name="any thing";
```

and then recall it like this

```
string name=GlobalClass.U_name;
```

Comment: I believe he is using a web form and trying to get the value of `U_Name` from a textbox.

Comment: [Why is Global State so Evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)